# How to delete older message not recent messages from kafka

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I'm trying to delete older messages from kafka it didnt works as expected. I have configure kafka
rentension.ms, log.cleanup propery also. But it didnt delete older messages after 5 mins. Here is the configuration and within 5 mins new messages also published eventhough older records present in kafka topic. can you please help me out what im missing in this configuration?. Because it increase storage cost.

-config retention.bytes=-1 --config cleanup.policy=delete --config retention.ms=300000

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to understand that the `LogCleaner` will only delete data on old segments of the topic, as described in the configuration description of `cleanup.policy`:

> "A string that is either "delete" or "compact" or both. This string designates the retention policy to use on **old** log segments."

It is likely that all your data is still in one segment, so you need to reduce the `segment.bytes` configuration for your topic such that you actually get "old" segments. This configuration default to 1GB and is described as:

> "This configuration controls the segment file size for the log. Retention and cleaning is always done a file at a time so a larger segment size means fewer files but less granular control over retention."

If you don't want to wait until a segment is being filled up, feel free to also reduce the configuration `segment.ms` from the default value of 7 days to something more fitting to your case. This config is described as:

> "This configuration controls the period of time after which Kafka will force the log to roll even if the segment file isn't full to ensure that retention can delete or compact old data."

If you have short retention times like 5 minutes you may also want to reduce the broker-wide configuration `log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms` from its default of 1 day to a lower value. This configuration is described as:

> "How long are delete records retained?"

Comment: Thanks @mike. log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms not working unknown configuration issue.please help me out, i dont want older messages only recent messages from the time of publish to 5 mins only data delete and recent messages present no issues